# MySQL Timestamp Difference

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a table with column timestam which stores a timestamp with this format: "2012-12-10 21:24:30"

I am looking for a SQL Query that takes the current timestamp and subtracts it with the one in the column and gives the difference in this format:

"3 Hours and 2 mins Remaining"

Looking for a MySQL Query that does that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)
```

> where unit argument, which should be one of the following values:
>   MICROSECOND (microseconds), SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH,
>   QUARTER, or YEAR.

**my approach :** set unit as **SECOND**  and then use **[SEC_TO_TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time)**

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`table`.`time_column`,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))

// will return in hh:mm:ii format
```

#### update

Return **yes** if `HourDifference` are less than 48 hours? otherwise **no**

```
SELECT IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,`time_column`,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())< 48  ,'yes','no')
```

Comment: how do I get the current timestamp? to put into "datetime_expr2"... is it NOW()?

Comment: Okay I got that to work... SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, users_codes.timestam, NOW()) AS HourDifference FROM users_codes

What would I do if I wanted to return 'yes' if the HourDifference was less than 48 hours? and return 'no' if it wasn't?

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I hope other people can learn from this too :)

Comment: Sorry to coem back to this over and over again... How can I return the rows that have only 'yes'?

Comment: put it into `WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(...) < 48`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 4):

Assume your table name is 'testtable'

Table create query is given below

```
CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
    `id` INT(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `period` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Insert some data to test my query. Query to insert some data is given below

```
INSERT INTO `testtable` (`id`, `period`) VALUES
    (1, '2012-12-10 17:21:09'),
    (2, '2012-11-06 18:21:12'),
    (3, '2012-12-06 18:21:18'),
    (4, '2012-12-06 19:21:24'),
    (5, '2012-12-06 18:21:27');
```

Now execute following query to get your answer

```
SELECT *, 
       CONCAT(HOUR(difftime), ' hours ', MINUTE(difftime), ' Minutes ', 
       SECOND(difftime), ' seconds remaining') AS timetaken 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP( 
               ttable.period)) AS 
                      diffTime 
        FROM   testtable ttable) AS temptable1
```

Output is given below

[image]

The column 'timetaken' will display answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I like the first solution better; however, other people may find your solution helpful.  Thanks Again.

Comment: +1 for `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` but I think `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())  ===  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: @diEcho - Thank you. I think UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) != CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(). Anyway +1 for your answer too because its a good answer

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()): 1441912971 ...
     UNIX_TIMESTAMP(): 1441912971 ...
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(): 2015-09-10 12:22:51 ...
                NOW(): 2015-09-10 12:22:51`