# MySQL Workbench Syntax Get difference of two timestamps

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Although I know how to get the time diff but I don't know how to convert the result to a format I wanted - Days Hours Minutes.

Any idea?

To illustrate:

```
 SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2009-05-18 11:45:42','2009-05-20 15:16:39')
```

result from running the query is : 3090

I need the MINUTE to be "Days Hours Minutes".

Comment: read this: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0280__Date-Time-Functions/TIMEFORMATtimeformat.htm

Comment: This will surely help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13813710