# MySQL where query by hour diff of 2 timestamps

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 2 timestamps: start_time and end_time. How can I query with conditions like select all where the diff of those 2 fields is more than X hours.

Also does the field type (timestamp vs datetime) has any impact on the query i'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Visit [ask]

Comment: i think i've got the answer below, so somebody must've understood the question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type of the fields does for sure have some differences.

As stated in [MySQL Timestamp Difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813675/mysql-timestamp-difference), it is usually the case that, given two datetime fields, they get converted to timestamps in order to subtract them.

The query could be something like

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,start_time,end_time)>2
```

Edit:
What written above is valid for MySQL, you can use [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) if you are working in SQL Server